# Column(fk) consisting more than 1 data(which is pk of other table)

Tags: php, mysql, database

Detail: 
Now I'm having 3 table. Customer, Maid, Booking

```
CustomerTable
+------+---+
| id(PK)   |
+------+---+
| name     |
+------+---+

MaidTable
+------+---+
| id(PK)   |
+------+---+
| name     |
+------+---+

BookingTable
+----------------+
| id(PK)         |
+----------------+
| CustomerID(FK) |  refer to customerTable
+----------------+
| MaidID(FK)     |  refer to maidTable 
+----------------+
```

Now my problem is, number of maid in a booking can be more than 1. That means the maidID(fk) in BookingTable will be more than 1 which is forbidden.

Where can I find about the constrain design information?
I need advices about the table design too. Thanks.

Comment: you can find [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/constraints.html)

Comment: Sounds like you should have an 1:N table between BookingTable and MaidTable. (That is, a table with BookingTable id and MaidTable id columns. Then you add one row in that table for each Maid in the Booking. Same BookingTable id for all rows.)

Comment: Improper use of `FOREIGN KEY`, if you're `AUTO_INCREMENT`ing your `PRIMARY KEY(id)`s.

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo if i have 1000+ of booking , am i having 1000+ of table ? Correct me if Im wrong. Thank!

Comment: @PHPglue should I remove the foreign key constrain? and just put in multiple values in single column ?

Comment: @wayne9003 No. Good heavens, you're sane if you question a design with thousands of tables that **still grows** ;)! **One** table for **all** booking-maid connections, with the two columns BookingID and MaidID.

Comment: @wayne9003 **Don't** store multiple values in one column/row. It is called comma separated list of doom, among others, and that's one of the nicer names for it.